# WPF, when inherit directly from Control, How to set default property like 'Background' in code?

Tags: wpf, controls

I'm trying to avoid using XAML in this control for some particular reason.

Then I create a new C# class named MyControl

```
class MyControl: Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        this.BorderBrush = SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush;
        this.Background = Brushes.Blue;
        this.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    }
}
```

And I created a WPF window and in XAML and add

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:....."
<local:MyControl Height="186" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" x:Name="mycontrol" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="331" />
```

but the Background property not working.
Any one can help me?

Comment: Your control needs a template, or it won't display at all...

Answer (score 1):

From the Remarks section in [Control Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx):

> A Control that does not have a ControlTemplate is not visible in your
>   application, and setting the following properties has no effect unless
>   the ControlTemplate references them explicitly:
>
> - Background
> - BorderBrush
> - BorderThickness
> - FontFamily
> - FontSize
> - FontStretch
> - FontWeight
> - Foreground
> - HorizontalContentAlignment
> - VerticalContentAlignment

Comment: so i have to create a ControlTemplate? if not use XAML, is it a good idea to create ControlTemplate in construct function?

Comment: @yylang1987, why don't you want to use XAML?

Comment: Try adding a Custom Control (WPF) to your Visual Studio project and see what it does. Creating a ControlTemplate in code wouldn't make much sense. You may also derive from a more specialized control like Label, depending on what your control should be.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to start with a `UserControl` and get familiar with its XAML.